# How could i pass the text from div to Noty jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery

I really like [Noty plugin](http://needim.github.com/noty/) but i can`t understand how could i pass some text to it.

I`ve got the following flash messages markup:

```
<div class="flash-messages">
   <div class="flash-message notice">Signed out successfully.</div>
</div>
```

To use noty i can simply call:

```
var noty = noty({text: 'noty - a jquery notification library!'});
```

But how could i pass the text from .flash-message to text option of the noty? 
I also want .notice .error classes to manipulate noty styles.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var noty = noty({text: $(".flash-message.notice").text()});
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the text from the `div` you can simply do:

```
var noticeText = $(".notice").text();
```

Which you can then insert into the `noty` call:

```
var noty = noty({text: noticeText});
```

Answer (score 1):

For class `.flash-message` you could do this:

```
var $flashMessage = $('.flash-message'),
    class = $('.flash-message').attr('class').replace('flash-message ', ''),
    noty = noty({text: $flashMessage.text(), type: class});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var myFlashMessages = [];
$(".flash-messages > .flash-message.notice").each(function(){
    myFlashMessages[myFlashMessages.length] = $(this).text();
});
```

The code above stores all the inner texts you are looking for in an array.